# What happens to the Gaussian as $\sigma \to \infty$ at $x \to \infty$?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

Does the Gaussian $N(0, \sigma^2)$ have a limiting distribution as $\sigma \to \infty$? And does the density in fact decay to 0 as $x \to \infty$?

If we want the ratio of the density at the mean over the density as $x$ also approaches infinity, we can set up the following iterated limit:

$$L := \lim_{\sigma \to \infty, x \to \infty} f(x)/f(0) = exp(-x^2/2\sigma^2)$$
$$\log L = \lim_{\sigma \to \infty, x \to \infty} -x^2/2\sigma^2$$

But can we solve for L or is it indeterminate? A cursory reading of Ivlev and Shilin (2014) suggests it is in fact indeterminate.

Reference:
Ivlev, V. V., and I. A. Shilin. "On a generalization of l'Hopital's rule for multivariable functions." arXiv preprint arXiv:1403.3006 (2014).

Comment: This question might be more suited to Math Stack  See discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177067/lhospital-rule-for-two-variable/177083 There is also paper of Lawlor https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0363  My understanding that the limit ($\sigma \to \infty, x \to \infty$) may not exist as there is also no simple change of variables.

Answer (score 7):

The limit $\log L$ is indeterminate because it will depend on the path that $(\sigma,x)$ takes to go to $(\infty,\infty)$.

Below are two examples where both $x$ and $\sigma$ approach infinity while the limiting value of the loglikelihood is different.

- If we use $x = n^2$ and $\sigma = n$ then $$\log L = -x^2/(2\sigma^2 )= -n^2/2$$ and the limit will go to minus infinity.
- If we use $x = n$ and $\sigma = n^2$ then $$\log L = -x^2/(2\sigma^2)= -1/(2n^2)$$ and the limit will go to zero.

Note that the limiting function of the normal distribution for $\sigma \to \infty$ is not a proper probability density function (because the limit is zero everywhere). What do you wanna do with it? What is it supposed to mean in practice?